# Refactoring to comply with the DRY principle

Tags: php, laravel, refactoring, dry

I am trying to find a way to refactor this code so I don't to repeat same code in many places. I am looking for DRY principle.

This is an example of `createDaemon()` method.

```
function createDaemon($server, $command, $user)
    {
        try {
            DB::beginTransaction();

            $model = $server->daemons()->create([
                'command' => $command,
                'user' => $user,
            ]);

            $shell = $this->getCommand('add-daemon', [
                'daemonId' => $daemon->id,
                'command' => $command,
                'user' => $user,
            ]);

            $this->pushToQueue($model, $shell);

            DB::commit();
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            DB::rollback();
            throw $e;
        }

        return $model;
    }
```

This is another example of `createRule()` in another class, as you can see the code is almost the same. How to refactor this into DRY principle - would you create a new method or class to do the same logic?

```
   public function createRule($server, $name, $port, $ipAddress = null)
    {
        try {
            DB::beginTransaction();

            $model = $server->rule()->create([
                'name' => $name,
                'port' => $port,
            ]);

            $shell = $this->getCommand('rule', [
                'port' => $port,
                'ipAddress' => $ipAddress
            ]);

            $this->pushToQueue($model, $shell);

            DB::commit();
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            DB::rollback();
            throw $e;
        }

        return $model;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I would create one common method like this:

```
public function createGeneralRule(Closure $closure)
{
    try {
        DB::beginTransaction();

        [$model, $shell] = $closure();

        $this->pushToQueue($model, $shell);

        DB::commit();
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        DB::rollback();
        throw $e;
    }

    return $model;
}
```

and now you can do use it like this:

```
function createDaemon($server, $command, $user)
{
    return $this->createGeneralRule(function() use ($server, $command, $user) {
        $model = $server->daemons()->create([
            'command' => $command,
            'user' => $user,
        ]);

        $shell = $this->getCommand('add-daemon', [
            'daemonId' => $daemon->id,
            'command' => $command,
            'user' => $user,
        ]);

        return [$model, $shell];
     }
}
```

and

```
public function createRule($server, $name, $port, $ipAddress = null)
{
    return $this->createGeneralRule(function() use ($server, $name, $port, $ipAddress) {
        $model = $server->rule()->create([
            'name' => $name,
            'port' => $port,
        ]);

        $shell = $this->getCommand('rule', [
            'port' => $port,
            'ipAddress' => $ipAddress
        ]);

        return [$model, $shell];
     }
 }
```

Of course you could also use classes, but it really depends how many times you are going to reuse this code and what flexibility do you really need.

Using classes it could be something like this:

```
abstract class Rule
{
    public function process()
    {
        try {
            DB::beginTransaction();

            $model = $this->model();
            $shell = $this->shell();

            $this->pushToQueue($model, $shell);

            DB::commit();
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            DB::rollback();
            throw $e;
        }

        return $model;
    }

    protected function getCommand($name, $data)
    {
        // here you put implementation you had before of getCommand
    }

    abstract protected function model();

    abstract protected function shell();
}

class Deamon extends Rule
{
    protected $server;
    protected $command;
    protected $user;

    public function __construct($server, $command, $user)
    {
        $this->server = $server;
        $this->command = $command;
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    protected function model()
    {
        return $this->server->daemons()->create([
            'command' => $this->command,
            'user' => $this->user,
        ]);
    }

    protected function shell()
    {
        return $this->getCommand('add-daemon', [
            'daemonId' => $daemon->id, // this is unknown, should be passed in constructor?
            'command' => $this->command,
            'user' => $this->user,
        ]);
    }
}
```

and in your controller you would use it like this:

(new Deamon($server, $command, $user))->process();

Just in case - keep in mind you have `$deamon` variable which is not defined (it's not defined also in your controller)

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is not correct `[$model, $shell] = $closure();`

Comment: Pretty neat. Are you be able to show example of using `classes`. It going to be reuse many times in many classes.

Comment: @I'll-Be-Back I've updated with simple class implementation

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix Awesome. What do you think of having methods like `createRule()` and `deleteRule()` in the `Deamon` class you have created but both methods use different get command key.

Answer (score 1):

**Extends**

You can make them extend the same base class:

```
class foo{
     public function myMethod(){}
}

class bar extends foo{ }

class biz extends foo{ }
```

Now both subclasses have the method `myMethod`

**Trait**

You can use a trait for the shared functionality

```
trait foo{
   public function myMethod(){}
}

class bar{
  use foo;
}

class biz{ 
  use foo;
}
```

As for the actual functionality I would break it down into 3 methods:
I was going to write something on it but I see @Marcin Nabiałek, has a good answer for that part. I just wanted to cover how to structure the classes in order to re-use a common method.

Cheers.

Comment: Unclear what do you mean by break it down into 3 methods. `createDaemon()` and `createRule()` is already separate method. Both method use `pushToQueue()`, `getCommand()` and the `->create([])` to create an entry in the db

Comment: see the answer by Marcin Nabiałek, which addresses the method itself, I was posting more about structuring the class, because even restructuring the method to be re-usable, doesn't address how to re-use it.  `This is another example of createRule() in another class`  So not only do they need to make it re-usable, but they must also structure the classes to make use of the re-usable methods.